# encoding/decoding json is giving me random decimals for all my numbers

Tags: php, json

The json I am reading has completely different numbers then the one that outputs to me. How can I fix this? I already tried using `round()` to round each number in a `foreach` loop. My php version is 7.2.13

external.json

```
{
    "fruits": {
        "banana": 84.4234563919,
        "apple": 0.0715972684,
        "orange": 4.808779748
    }
}
```

output.json

```
{
    "fruits": {
        "banana": 84.4234563919000038367812521755695343017578125,
        "apple": 0.0715972683999999970350103239979944191873073577880859375,
        "orange": 4.80877974800000007604694474139250814914703369140625
    }
}
```

test.php

```
<?php

    $contents1 = file_get_contents("external.json");
    $json1 = json_decode($contents1, TRUE);

    $new_json = json_encode($json1, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    file_put_contents("test.json", $new_json);

?>
```

test2.php (trying to use round function) but still the same result

```
<?php

    $contents1 = file_get_contents("external.json");
    $json1 = json_decode($contents1, TRUE);

    foreach ($json1['fruits'] as $key=>$value) {
        $new_json['fruits'][$key] = round($value, 2);
    }

    $encoded_json = json_encode($new_json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    file_put_contents("test.json", $encoded_json );

?>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue with straight PHP as you have above.
Usually this issue occurs in Javascript.

Comment: @Emmanuel I have no javascript in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in php 7.0 double numbers has this problem.

see this [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72567)

my answer is change double numbers to string and after decode change it to number (you can add zero after decode)

or you can change your **php.ini**

```
serialize_precision = -1
```

see [precision integer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision)

You can add a empty string to each double value of your array,
Example for test2.php:

```
<?php

$contents1 = file_get_contents("external.json");
$json1 = json_decode($contents1, TRUE);

foreach ($json1['fruits'] as $key=>$value) {
    $new_json['fruits'][$key] = round($value, 2).'';
}

$encoded_json = json_encode($new_json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
file_put_contents("test.json", $encoded_json );

?>
```

Comment: Can you show me how using my `test2.php` code as an example?

Comment: What if I want the original value? I don't want to round to anything, but just the original value from the `external.json`?

Comment: when the number is changed you can not find the real number but you can found near number to it with [round()](http://ir2.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)